# python Selenium filter images creative commons

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Português:
Como faço um filtro para download de imagens no google imagens, creative commons?
Já busquei a documentação em https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol e não encontrei nada.

English:
How do I make a filter for downloading images on google images, creative commons?
I've already looked for the documentation at https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol and haven't found anything.

código / code: font:https://github.com/YoongiKim/AutoCrawler/blob/master/main.py

```
#! python3

# Google Images Downloader.py - search and download Images from google.com
# this script will open the web browser using selenium and search for Images(1920x1080 minimum/FULL HD), get their links, and download them.
# I Mainly use this script to automatically download desktop wallpapers.
# run this code in CLI using >>> py Google\ Images\ Downloader.py

# NOTE: Images found using this script is NOT a duplicate-FREE, duplicate images maybe be downloaded again and get new random name
# if you search with the same term again were a new folder won't be created since it already exist and images found will be saved to that folder.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import requests, os, time
from uuid import uuid4
from plyer import notification
from colorama.ansi import Fore as CLI_TextColor

# XPATH location of the image resolution.
Image_Resolution_XPath = '//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/span' 
# XPATH location of the image URL with checkers that starts with "https" and ends with an image file extention (.jpg or .jpeg or .png)
ImageXPath_with_checkers = '//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/img\
    [@src[starts-with(., "https") and substring(., (string-length(.) - string-length(".jpg") + 1)) = ".jpg"\
              or substring(., string-length(.) - string-length(".jpeg") + 1) = ".jpeg"\
                   or substring(., string-length(.) - string-length(".png") + 1) = ".png"]]'

# Footer location in ViewPort, The program will end when the footer is visible in ViewPort(on screen)
FooterCurrentViewPort = """
footer_currentVP = document.querySelector('#ZCHFDb').getBoundingClientRect();
if (footer_currentVP.top != 0 && footer_currentVP.bottom != 0 && footer_currentVP.right != 0) { 
    return (
        footer_currentVP.top >= 0 &&
        footer_currentVP.left >= 0 &&
        footer_currentVP.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        footer_currentVP.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );} else {return (false) }
"""

ChromiumBrave = Options()
ChromiumBrave.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"
ChromeDriverPATH = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
Search_URL = "http://www.google.com/search?q={q}&tbm=isch"

Success_downloads = 0
Failure_downloads = 0
FailedToSaveImage = 0

def fetch_image_URLs(search_query: str, MAX_number_of_images: int, wd: webdriver):
    """Locate and fetch image URLs from google.com/imghp"""
    def scroll_page(wd: webdriver):
        """Scroll the page down from it's current position + length of window ViewPort"""
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);")
        time.sleep(3.5)

    wd.get(Search_URL.format(q=search_query))
    print("Looking for images, Please wait...", flush=True)

    image_links = set()
    image_count = 0
    starting_position = 0

    while image_count < MAX_number_of_images:
        scroll_page(wd)
        FooterVisibilityInViewPort = wd.execute_script(FooterCurrentViewPort)
        if not FooterVisibilityInViewPort: # keep looking for images when the Footer is not visible in ViewPort.

            # find all image thumbnails in the page
            try:
                ImageThumbnails = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Q4LuWd'))
            except Exception:
                continue

            for image in ImageThumbnails[starting_position:len(ImageThumbnails)]:
                try: # click to open each image to find the real image url.
                    image.click()
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                except Exception:
                    continue # try the next image!
                
                # check the image resolution!
                if check_image_resolution(wd):
                    try:
                        # wait for a correct image url to be found using XPATH expression, this works well with WebDriverWait.
                        # using XPATH expression saves a lot of time from writing unwanted regex code, XPATH is like regex but for web pages, it uses XML path expression within the HTML DOM structure.
                        image_URL = WebDriverWait(wd, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ImageXPath_with_checkers))).get_attribute('src')
                    except Exception:
                        continue # try the next image!

                    image_links.add(image_URL)

                    if len(image_links) >= MAX_number_of_images:
                        print(f"\n{CLI_TextColor.GREEN}Done, Found {len(image_links)} images{CLI_TextColor.RESET}\n", flush=True)
                        return image_links # Done!
                else:
                    continue # check the next image for a better resolution

            image_count = len(image_links)
            starting_position = len(ImageThumbnails)

        else: # Footer is visible in ViewPort!
            print("Looks like you've reached the end!".center(30, '-'), flush=True)
            if len(image_links) >= 1:
                print(f"{CLI_TextColor.BLUE}Got {len(image_links)} out of {MAX_number_of_images} images!{CLI_TextColor.RESET}", flush=True)
                return image_links

            else: # this happens when no images have been found!
                print(f"{CLI_TextColor.RED}Sorry, Couldn't find any images!")
                wd.quit() # close the web browser window
                notification.notify("Failed to find images!", f"Sorry, Couldn't find any images", app_icon=r".\\Notification Icons\vcsconflicting.ico")
                raise SystemExit # exit/end the program

def check_image_resolution(wd: webdriver):
    """Check an image resolution, minimum image resolution should be Full HD(1920 x 1080)"""
    Minimum_Width, Minimum_Hight = 1920, 1080
    try:
        # Find the image resolution, the resolution is based of what google is displaying when you hover over the image.
        # Checking the image resolution without downloading the image itself to save data (this is not a perfect way of getting an image resolution!).
        ImageWidth, unknownCharacter, ImageHight = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Image_Resolution_XPath))).get_attribute("textContent").split(' ')
    except Exception:
        return False
    ImageWidth, ImageHight = ImageWidth.replace(',', ''), ImageHight.replace(',', '') 
    return True if int(ImageWidth) >= Minimum_Width and int(ImageHight) >= Minimum_Hight else False

def download_and_save_image(image_url: str, folder_path: str):
    """Download and save the image to a targeted folder with a random name assigned to the image file"""

    global Success_downloads
    global Failure_downloads
    global FailedToSaveImage

    try:
        image_content = requests.get(image_url) # download the image content!
        image_content.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as FailedToDownloadImageError:
        Failure_downloads += 1
        return print(f"\n{CLI_TextColor.RED}ERROR - Couldn't download image: {image_url} - {FailedToDownloadImageError}{CLI_TextColor.RESET}\n", flush=True)
    
    NewImageName = os.path.join(folder_path, str(uuid4()).replace('-', '')[:12] + os.path.splitext(image_url)[-1])
    # os.path.splitext(image_url)[-1] is to get the image extention out of image_url.
    # The final name would be like >>> D:\Omar\Pictures\Downloaded Images from google\<query>\54afh91a97sf.(jpg or jpeg or png)
    try: # open a new image file and save the image_content to it!
        with open(NewImageName, 'wb') as NewImage:
            for chunk in image_content.iter_content(100000):
                NewImage.write(chunk)
        Success_downloads += 1
    except Exception as FailedToSaveImageError:
        FailedToSaveImage += 1
        return print(f"\n{CLI_TextColor.YELLOW}ERROR - Couldn't save image: {image_url} - {FailedToSaveImageError}{CLI_TextColor.RESET}\n", flush=True)

def download_images_from_google(search_query: str, driver_path: str, number_of_images: int, targeted_Folder=r"D:\Omar\Pictures\Downloaded Images from google"):
    with webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_path, options=ChromiumBrave) as wd: # This web driver will open Brave web browser.
        wd.maximize_window()
        URLs = fetch_image_URLs(search_query, number_of_images, wd)

    Folder_path = os.path.join(targeted_Folder, search_query)
    # Create a folder in the targeted_folder with the search_query name, if that folder doesn't exists, it'll be created.
    if not os.path.exists(Folder_path):
        os.makedirs(Folder_path)
        print(f"{CLI_TextColor.MAGENTA}Folder created: {Folder_path}{CLI_TextColor.RESET}", flush=True)

    print(f"{CLI_TextColor.CYAN}Downloading the images, Please wait...{CLI_TextColor.RESET}", flush=True)
    for URL in URLs:
        download_and_save_image(URL, Folder_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    UserSearchQuery = input("Images to search for: ")
    NumberOfImagesToSearch = int(input("Number of images to download: ") or 5)
    download_images_from_google(UserSearchQuery, ChromeDriverPATH, NumberOfImagesToSearch)
    result = f"Download complete: {CLI_TextColor.GREEN}{Success_downloads} Success, {CLI_TextColor.RED}{Failure_downloads} Failures"
    print(result + f", {CLI_TextColor.YELLOW}{FailedToSaveImage} Failed to save images" if FailedToSaveImage > 0 else result, flush=True)
    # notify me when finish downloading.
    notification.notify("Download complete!", f"Downloaded {Success_downloads} images", app_icon=r".\\Notification Icons\iconfinder-check.ico")
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Aproveitando para responder minha própria dúvida: o filtro creative commons do google imagens para utilização dentro do Selenium, pelo python, é feita pela URL de busca. Para aqueles que precisem dessa informação, segue: ```http://www.google.com/search?q={q}&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:lt%2Cislt:xga%2Cil:cl  ```  onde o {q} é a fonte de busca, descrita nesse código.